# Fit N rectangles within area keeping aspect ratio

Tags: algorithm, math, rectangles

I have N rectangles, all of the same dimensions **rectWidth*****rectHeight**.
I have an area with dimensions **areaWidth*****areaHeight**.
I want to fit the N rectangles within the area keeping the aspect ratio of the rectangles, resizing the rectangles to make them fit.
Between the rectangles I want a spacing of **space**.

What should be the dimensions of the rectangles to fit them all within the rectangle and keeping the aspect ratio?

Comment: You will need to specify this a bit better. Right now the problem is very underconstrained: I could just resize all rectangles to be 0x0. Do you want a particular placement? Should they all be resized by the same factor?

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your reply. Placement is not an issue, I feed the rectangles to a control that places them. All N rectangles have the same dimensions, and must keep the same dimensions in the new situation. I want them to be their original size (rectWidth*rectHeight), or smaller if they don't all fit. The result of the algorithm should be the factor to resize them with so they will fit. If this factor > 1 I leave it the way it is, if the factor < 1 I resize all rectangles by that factor. I hope this explains the requirements and constraints good enough.

Comment: I believe the question should be rephrased to: What should be the MAX dimensions of the rectangles to fit them all within the rectangle and keeping the aspect ratio?

Comment: I tried a direct formula approach, which tells me that a should be close to NR/r or b close to Nr/R, with R the aspect ratio of your area and r and N the aspect ratio and number of rectangles respectively, and a and b the number of rectangles in the area's width and height respectively. Before I take into account spacing, can anyone find configuration that gives wrong results with this http://jsfiddle.net/ohbhy4uw/ ?

Answer (score 5):

Let there be N rectangles.
Let the rectangles be size (cw, ch), where 0 < c ≤ 1.
Let the region you want to fit in be size (W, H).
Let s ≥ 0 be the spacing between rectangles.

The horizontal size of a > 0 rectangles stacked horizontally is acw + (a - 1)s.
We know acw + (a - 1)s ≤ W.

The vertical size of b > 0 rectangles stacked vertically is bch + (b - 1)s.
We know bch + (b - 1)s ≤ H.

We then have the following optimization problem.

max c
subject to
a ≤ (W + s) / (cw + s)
b ≤ (H + s) / (ch + s)
ab ≥ N
0 < c ≤ 1
a, b > 0 and integer

Now consider the following inequalities.

a ≤ (W + s) / (cw + s)
b ≤ (H + s) / (ch + s)

Any optimal solution must make at least one of these a tight inequality.
That is, at least one of the following holds for the optimal solution (a, b, c).

a = (W + s) / (cw + s) ↔ c = (W - s(a - 1)) / wa
b = (H + s) / (ch + s) ↔ c = (H - s(b - 1)) / wb

Let's suppose without loss of generality that a = (W + s) / (cw + s) holds.
Since a must take one of the values in {1, 2, ..., N},
c must take one of the values in {W / w, (W - s) / 2w, (W - 2s) / 3w, ..., (W - (N - 1)s) / Nw}.

Similar reasoning gives a list of values c must be drawn from in the case where the second inequality (for b) is tight.

If you merge these two lists of values, you will have at most 2N possible values c can take in the optimal solution. Sort those values, then binary search for the maximum c in this list for which there are feasible a and b.

The way to check if a value of c is feasible is to set

a = floor((W + s) / (cw + s))
b = floor((H + s) / (ch + s))

and then check that ab ≥ N.

Comment: This looks brilliant... but need to study on this:-) We (Pi=31415926 & I) will try to convert this into a JavaScript function:-)

Comment: hm... so I need to do 2 loops over N elements to collect all possible values of c. How this is faster then my solution where I iterate less then N times? I'm gonna add some explanation to my answer...

Comment: @31415926 The problem with the method you posted is that it will not always work.

Comment: could you be more specific?

Comment: @31415926 From your answer: "The function assumes that grid of rectangles (canvas) will always fit the height of a container area."  This is an invalid assumption.  If you take away this assumption, you're left with the statement I made: either it fills the full width or it fills the full height.  Under that premise you can derive an algorithm as I have described.  Note that my algorithm is *extremely* cheap and easy to implement.  Don't assume the long derivation means the implementation is complicated.

Comment: Strictly speaking you are right - iteration should be done also for columns and bigger rect size should be chosen. Using only row iterator will always fit the container but rect size would not always be optimal.

Comment: @31415926 It's not just some weird edge case though. If there are 2 rectangles sized (2, 2) and the container is size (2, 1) and the spacing is 0, your algorithm will choose to make the rectangles sized (0.5, 0.5) instead of the optimal (1, 1).  Downvoting my answer and then modifying your own to mimic my answer is very poor behavior...

Comment: well I just tested with areaWidth = 2; areaHeight=1; N=2; rectRatio=1; gutter = [0, 0] and it gives optimal result (1, 1); rowIteratot gives (1,1) and colIterator gives (1,1)

Comment: I downvoted because I think the algorithm is less efficient due to 2N loops and due to assumption 0 < c ≤ 1. If you will have w,h smaller then fitted rect size then c would be > 1. In addition you need to check if value of c is feasible.. which is an additional loop. Will upvote your answer asa you edit it.

Comment: @31415926 From the comments on the question: **"I want them to be their original size (rectWidth*rectHeight), or smaller if they don't all fit."** You're becoming a little silly with the criticisms, so I'm going to refrain from discussing any more.

Comment: @31415926 Both your algorithm and this one are exactly the same, if not for the assumption that `c <= 1` and the fact that you check for feasibility earlier (i.e. in the first loop). You both assume one direction will be packed (no free space except "gutters"), iterate over all numbers of possible rectangles in each direction, take the maximum feasible value and then take the max result of both directions. Whether you do two O(n) loops and one O(2n) loop like Timothy, or two O(n) loops with twice as many instructions like you is strictly the same.

Answer (score 2):

How about this javaScript solution?

```
var areaHeight = window.innerHeight;   //set here your area height
var areaWidth = window.innerWidth;     //set here your area width
var N = 216;                           //set amount of rectangles you want to fit
var rectRatio = 9/4;                   //set rectangle ratio
var gutter = [5, 10];                  //set x and y spacing between rectangles
var cols, rows, rectHeight, rectWidth; //variables that we need to calculate
```

The function assumes that grid of rectangles (canvas) will always fit the height of a container area. You feed number of rows to the function and it calculates rect size and determines whether canvas width is bigger than container width or not. If canvas is bigger we do rows++ and call the function again.

```
function rowIterator(iterator) {
   rows = iterator;
   cols = Math.ceil(N/rows);  

   rectHeight = (areaHeight - (rows-1)*gutter[1])/rows;          
   rectWidth = rectHeight*rectRatio;

   if (cols * rectWidth + (cols - 1)*gutter[0] > areaWidth) {
       rowIterator(rows + 1);
   }
}

rowIterator(1);                       //feed initial value
var size1 = [rectWidth, rectHeight];
```

If you also care about finding MAX rect size and not only fit it then iteration should be done also for columns and bigger rect size should be chosen:

```
function colIterator(iterator) {
   cols = iterator;
   rows = Math.ceil(N/cols);

   rectWidth = (areaWidth - (cols - 1)*gutter[0])/cols;
   rectHeight = rectWidth/rectRatio;

   if (rows * rectHeight + (rows - 1)*gutter[1] > areaHeight) {
       colIterator(cols + 1);
   }
}
colIterator(1);
var size2 = [rectWidth, rectHeight];
```

total amount of iterations for both iterators would be around N, the max rectangle size is:

```
optimalRectSize = [Math.max(size1[0], size2[0]), Math.max(size1[1], size2[1])]
```